# How to Stream a Guzzle Response to the browser?

Tags: php, guzzle

I am loading video via a 3rd party API.
It returns the binary in the body, with the `Transfer-Encoding :chunked` header.

I'm using `Guzzle 4` to consume the api, how can I easily stream this to the browser so I don't need to load the whole thing up into memory in PHP first?

I don't want to set it as an `attachment`, as I want it to play in the browser rather than download.

```
<?php

$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();

// Download the video and stream it to the client
$response = $client->get($url)->send();

//But this will have to cache the whole thing in PHP memory first...
header("Content-Type:{$response->getHeader('Content-Type')}");
echo $response->getBody();
```

Comment: Besides Guzzle, do you know what else is an HTTP client? The user's browser. Why not let it consume the video directly?

Comment: Because the content is behind a private API that our application (not the user) authenticates with.  I basically need to proxy the request for the video from the browser, via our app to perform the auth and some other things, and then return the video to the consuming client.  If the 3rd party API provided a pre-authed URL like S3, then I could just redirect any request to that, but all I have is this stream, and I cant see a simple way to proxy it...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If anyone else was looking at this...

Guzzle 4 responses are NOT streams by default (they are in the latest version) you have to enable that in the request options..

```
['stream'=>true]
```

And then use the `Stream` util to read each line of the stream..

```
GuzzleHttp\Stream\Utils::readline
```

So....

```
<?php

$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();

// Download the video as a stream
$response = $client->request('GET', $url, ['stream'=>true])->send();

//$body is now a Guzzle stream object.
$body = $response->getBody();

header("Content-Type:{$response->getHeader('Content-Type')}");

while (!$body->eof()) {
  echo GuzzleHttp\Stream\Utils::readline($body);
  ob_flush();
  flush();
}
```